# scroll vs. paint

Tags: ipad, scroll, paint

I'm stuck on the following:

I'd like to be able to paint into a view within a UIScrollView and still allow scrolling. I've seen it done in one program. Two fingers down and you can pinch zoom and scroll. One finger down and you draw. If delaysContentTouches=NO, I'm having a very difficult time detecting when two fingers are down reliably unless both fingers come down perfectly. If delaysContentTouches=YES, then it's easy to determine the two fingers, but single finger drawing doesn't work because the swipe is considered a scroll. Any ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the pan gesture minimum number of touches to 2. That does it.